# Can't access variable in $resource's callbacks

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory that use $resource to communicate with a REST API. The problem comes when I delete an object and then I try to query in the callback to keep the same number of elements in the list. It's like I can´t access to any variable in the callback function who looks like that:

```
    this.delete = function() {
        var item = new Luminaria(this.selectedtem);

        item.$delete(function(){
            this.selectedtem = this.emptyItem();
            this.backupItem = undefined;
            this.items = Luminaria.query();
        });
        $("#itemModal").modal('hide');
    }
```

'this' is undefined inside the callback function... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `$resource` to communicate with a REST API the result will be `asynchronous`. Hence you cannot access the variables in the callback function.

Comment: That was quick... thanks! Any idea of how can I resolve this thing?

Comment: You could use $http instead of $resource.